# Invariant violation reading JSON data

Tags: reactjs, object, react-native

I have reviewed all similar errors on the forum but none fixes my issue. Not sure what I am doing wrong trying to read a JSON data that exists (confirmed with console.log) and also an array but being told it is an object and needs to be an array. Mapping over the array directly without doing the for-loop shown basically says object gallery is undefined even though it is defined.console.log of itemList shows empty implying gallery is undefined. How can that be when console.log of gallery returned the 6-element gallery array?  Please see respective code snippets and image of error log below.
 Thanks for your help ad pointer.

```
render() {
const { showModal, articleData } = this.props;
const { 
  image, gallery,title, subTitle, description,location, phone, credit 
} = articleData;
console.log(gallery);

let itemList = [];
for (let i in gallery) {
  itemList.push({
    ...gallery[i],
    // id: key
  })
  return itemList
}
console.log(itemList);

<View style= {{ flex: 1 }}>
              <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => 
                  this._toggleModal(1)
                }
              >

              {
                itemList.map((v, index) => {
                  return (
                    <View key= {index}  >
                      <Image 
                        style={styles.navImageStyle}
                        source={{ uri: v.photo}}
                      />
                      {/* <Text>{v.desc}</Text>
                      <Text>{v.price}</Text> */}
                    </View>
                  )
                })
              }
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

[image: error from debugger]

Comment: Seems to be a typo... `v.ticket` not `v.price` Also, comment out the Image tag and see if you still get the same error...

Comment: Sakobu, I am not sure I understand your advice about typo of v.ticket. The entire text output was commented out and the reference to v.price really doesn't matter in that case. My main issue is how an array is being considered an object which may be an error of how I am trying to read the data or even define the json data.  Thanks though. The image tag or a correct text tag didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot of the response you seem to have `desc, open, phone, photo, ticket` I do not see `price`

Comment: Is this a public API that you're getting the data from? If so, post the link here...

Comment: Thanks Sakub. I understand the v.price typo but it is not the issue as that data is not being accessed at all. Plus I have corrected that and still getting the same error. Here's the link to the data source. https://manager-5c9cd.firebaseio.com/

Comment: No, the issue is the structure of your data... that was just a side note... what you provided is not a public API... it’s a firebase db that I do not access to... sorry can’t help... Good luck in your learning journey...